# How to add --watch parameter to coffee command?

Tags: coffeescript

I have this: `coffee --output extension/javascripts/ --compile app.coffee` and I want to add --watch parameter. How can I implement this?

because when I do so, it does not work

```
─$ coffee --output extension/javascripts/ --compile app.coffee --watch
File not found: --watch.coffee
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
coffee -o extension/javascripts/  -cw app.coffee
```

You can combine commands. (so `cw` is compile and watch)

Comment: @milushov well that just means there is something wrong in your files or in your path.